# Shapefile licence agreement when publishing map made with R's maps package

Tags: r, maps, license

I am submitting an article that has a map I made using `R`'s data from R's `maps` package. I know that most shapefiles come with a license user-agreement or copyright information that accompanies the map as an annotation.

Where can I find the license agreements for maps made with data from `R` `maps`?

Comment: Do you mean the `maps` package? You're inconsistent. There is no `map` package, so I'll edit the title etc.

Comment: Which map data specifically are you talking about? The `maps` package will often be getting data from the `mapdata` package which uses data derived from the CIA world data bank: https://www.evl.uic.edu/pape/data/WDB/

Comment: @Spacedman, thanks, I'm using the world data from the `maps` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean [`maps`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=maps) (with *s* at the end), then it is GPL-2 (https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=maps), like `R` (https://www.r-project.org/about.html)